# Python is printing one list backwards but not the others

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-1.8

I'm using Django 1.8 with a MySQL backend. I need to get two columns from several tables in a database and concatenate them, then put the sorted results on a webpage. I have this so far:

**views.py**

```
def herps(request):
    #performs queries to get distinct species from the database

    trQuery = queryBuilder(HetrRec, '_hetr')
    opQuery = queryBuilder(HeopRec, '_heop')

    valList = opQuery + trQuery

    query = sorted(set(valList))
return render_to_response('herps.html', {'queries': query,})
```

The function to perform the query on the database looks like this:

```
def queryBuilder(table, column_str):

    genus = 'genus' + column_str
    species = 'species' + column_str
    filterSp = {species: 'sp.'}

query = table.objects.order_by(species, genus).values(genus, species).distinct().exclude(**filterSp)
valueList = []
for q in query:
    species = ' '.join(q.values())
    valueList.append(species)

return(valueList)
```

So the output comes out in several table combinations as Genus Species. In one table it comes out Species Genus.

I've been through thte data to remove any characters that might affect it (leading / trailing spaces, incomplete pairs etc) but no joy.

Comment: of the two lists you're building, which one is correct and which do you think is backwards?

Comment: trQuery comes out correct, opQuery back to front. I've tried changing the order of the call to queryBuilder() and used other tables (including chaining multiple queries from several different tables). It's only the one table that comes out consistently with the concatenation back to front (Species then genus rather than Genus then species).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll shorten the code to the specific part that was very likely the issue:

```
query = table.objects.values(genus, species)
valueList = []
for q in query:
    species = ' '.join(q.values())
    valueList.append(species)
```

As you read in the documentation, `values()` will return a list of dictionaries, like this:

```
[{'genus_hetr': 'foogenus', 'species_hetr': 'foospecie'},
 {'genus_hetr': 'bargenus', 'species_hetr': 'barspecie'}]
```

You would then iterate through that list. On each iteration, `q` is one of the dicionaries. So far so good. Then, the issue:

```
' '.join(q.values())
```

A dictionary has no ordering. So this would join all values alright, but in an arbitrary order. Even those table you thought were working would have broken randomly at a later point.

So how to fix that? Well, like you did, using `values_list` returns tuples, which are ordered. Another option would have been to not rely on the order, but use the dictionary as such, that is, addressing it by key:

```
species = '%s %s' % (q[genus], q[species])
```

By the way, for such a simple case you probably want to use a list comprehension. The whole loop can be written like this:

```
valuesList = ['%s %s' % (q[genus], q[species]) for q in query]
```

Comment: Thanks so much spectras. The list comprehension worked. Much cleaner approach to it than my fumblings and thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As the docs would have it, instead of returning a dictionary (that was back to front for that one table), there is an option to return a value list. This came out the right way round and so the queryBuilder() function works like this:

**views.py**

```
def queryBuilder(table, column_str):

genus = 'genus_' + column_str
species = 'species_' + column_str
filterSp = {species: 'sp.'}


query = table.objects.values_list(genus, species).distinct().exclude(**filterSp)
valueList = []
for q in sorted(query):
    species = ' '.join(q)
    valueList.append(species)

return(valueList)
```

I still don't know why the previous query was coming out the wrong way around for that one table which is annoying.